# Load a website within wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I developed a plugin that needs to show some information at the end, and for that purpose I have a template inside my plugin.

Which one is the proper way to call all wordpress headers for the html to render properly ?

Comment: Are you adding content to an existing page? Creating a new page? Displaying a complete page in a window?

Comment: I was creating a new page. At the end I created the website from "scratch" using the get_header and get_footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already figure this up. At the end I just called the core wordpress components as it was a template, and change the content to what I wanted.

```
get_header();
get_footer();
```

With those 2 functions I could call everything that I needed to create my website withing my plugin.